# Login doesn't work for a medical system because of a mistake (System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Tags: c#

I have this code for a project. It's a medical system. You can enter the system either as an admin or as a doctor. Entering via Admin's username and password work while doctor's doesn't.

The code

```
class Program
{
    static List<User> users = new List<User>();
    static List<Doctor> doctors = new List<Doctor>();
    static List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();
    static User authenticatedUser;

    static ChiefDoctor chiefDoctor = new ChiefDoctor();

    class User
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string ContactInfo { get; set; }
    }

    class Patient : Person
    {
        public Doctor AttendingDoctor { get; set; }
        public List<Diagnosis> Diagnoses { get; set; } = new List<Diagnosis>();
        public List<Medication> Medications { get; set; } = new List<Medication>();
        public List<PatientAssessment> Assessments { get; set; } = new List<PatientAssessment>();
        public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; } = new List<Notification>();
    }

    class Doctor : Person
    {
        public string Specialty { get; set; }
        public List<Patient> Patients { get; set; } = new List<Patient>();
    }

    class ChiefDoctor : Doctor
    {
        public List<Diagnosis> PossibleDiagnoses { get; set; } = new List<Diagnosis>();

        public void AddPossibleDiagnosis(Diagnosis diagnosis)
        {
            PossibleDiagnoses.Add(diagnosis);
        }

        public void ViewPossibleDiagnoses()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Possible Diagnoses:");
            foreach (var diagnosis in PossibleDiagnoses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{diagnosis.Name} - Diagnosed by {diagnosis.DiagnosingDoctor.Name} on {diagnosis.DiagnosisTime}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Diagnosis
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Doctor DiagnosingDoctor { get; set; }
        public DateTime DiagnosisTime { get; set; }
    }

    class Medication
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Dosage { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }

    class PatientAssessment
    {
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
        public DateTime AssessmentDate { get; set; }
        public string AssessmentNotes { get; set; }
        public int HeartRate { get; set; }
        public int BloodPressure { get; set; }
    }

    class Notification
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        users.Add(new User { Username = "doctor1", Password = "password1", Role = "Doctor" });
        users.Add(new User { Username = "doctor2", Password = "password2", Role = "Doctor" });
        users.Add(new User { Username = "chiefdoctor", Password = "chiefpass", Role = "ChiefDoctor" });
        users.Add(new User { Username = "admin", Password = "adminpass", Role = "Admin" });

        var doctor1 = new Doctor { Name = "Dr. Smith", Specialty = "General Practitioner" };
        var doctor2 = new Doctor { Name = "Dr. Johnson", Specialty = "Surgeon" };

        chiefDoctor.AddPossibleDiagnosis(new Diagnosis { Name = "Flu", DiagnosingDoctor = chiefDoctor, DiagnosisTime = DateTime.Now });
        chiefDoctor.AddPossibleDiagnosis(new Diagnosis { Name = "Common Cold", DiagnosingDoctor = chiefDoctor, DiagnosisTime = DateTime.Now });

        var patient1 = new Patient
        {
            Name = "Patient1",
            DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980, 1, 15),
            Gender = "Male",
            ContactInfo = "Phone: 123-456-7890",
        };

        var patient2 = new Patient
        {
            Name = "Patient2",
            DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1995, 5, 25),
            Gender = "Female",
            ContactInfo = "Phone: 987-654-3210",
        };

        doctors.Add(doctor1);
        doctors.Add(doctor2);
        doctors.Add(chiefDoctor);
        patients.Add(patient1);
        patients.Add(patient2);

        LoadData();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Medical Records System.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please log in.");

            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            authenticatedUser = AuthenticateUser(username, password);

            if (authenticatedUser != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Logged in as {authenticatedUser.Role}.");

                if (authenticatedUser.Role == "Admin")
                {
                    AdminMenu();


                    SaveData();
                }
                else if (authenticatedUser.Role == "Doctor")
                {
                    var doctor = doctors.OfType<Doctor>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == authenticatedUser.Username);
                    DoctorMenu(doctor);


                    SaveData();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Access denied. You are not authorized to use this system.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password. Please try again.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }


    static User AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Username == username && user.Password == password);
    }

    static void AdminMenu()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Admin Menu:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add Doctor");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Add Patient");
            Console.WriteLine("3. View Patient Information");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Add Diagnosis");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Edit Patient Information");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Add Medication");
            Console.WriteLine("7. Check Patient's Critical Condition");
            Console.WriteLine("8. View Possible Diagnoses (Chief Doctor)");
            Console.WriteLine("9. Create Notification");
            Console.WriteLine("10. Admin View All Patient Data");
            Console.WriteLine("11. Assign Doctor to Patient");
            Console.WriteLine("12. Exit");

            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    AddDoctor();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    AddPatient();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ViewPatientInfo();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    AddDiagnosis();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    EditPatientInfo();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    AddMedication();
                    break;
                case "7":
                    CheckCriticalCondition();
                    break;
                case "8":
                    if (authenticatedUser.Role == "ChiefDoctor")
                        chiefDoctor.ViewPossibleDiagnoses();
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Access denied. You are not the Chief Doctor.");
                    break;
                case "9":
                    CreateNotification();
                    break;
                case "10":
                    AdminViewAllPatientData();
                    break;
                case "11":
                    AssignDoctorToPatient();
                    break;
                case "12":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please select again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void DoctorMenu(Doctor doctor)
    {


        if (authenticatedUser.Role != "Doctor")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access denied. You are not authorized to use this menu.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine($"Doctor Menu - Dr. {doctor.Name} ({doctor.Specialty}):");
            Console.WriteLine("1. View Patient Information");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Add Diagnosis");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Edit Patient Information");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Add Medication");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Check Patient's Critical Condition");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Exit");

            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    ViewPatientInfo();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    AddDiagnosis();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    EditPatientInfo();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    AddMedication();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    CheckCriticalCondition();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please select again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

after this there are the implementations of functions

It was supposed to work both when entering as a doctor and when entering as an admin but it does not work with doctor.

Comment: Doctors do not have Username in your code. ```var doctor1 = new Doctor { Name = "Dr. Smith", Specialty = "General Practitioner" };```  So, ```var doctor = doctors.OfType<Doctor>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == authenticatedUser.Username);``` will be null.

Answer (score 1):

> .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == authenticatedUser.Username)

You have no doctors with the same name as a user with a username. You need to give them the same names as their usernames, or add another property to Doctor called "username" and compare that.

Answer (score 0):

i would guess that this part

```
else if (authenticatedUser.Role == "Doctor")
            {
                var doctor = doctors.OfType<Doctor>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == authenticatedUser.Username);
                DoctorMenu(doctor);


                SaveData();
            }
```

returns null value, and you're brining in null value into doctorMenu method. Make a connection with Doctor and Users, so for example each Doctor has User  property.